# i want to use transaction with my code in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I am using `SqlDataAdapter` and `SqlCommandBuilder` to insert and update, and I want to use transaction to insert into two tables with this way but I have tried a lot and I didn't succeed
thanks

```
Dim sql = "select * from ReceiptOfItems where receiptCode=N'" & receiptCode.Text & "'  "
            Dim dta As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sql, con)
            Dim ds As New DataSet
            dta.Fill(ds)
            Dim dt As DataTable
            dt = ds.Tables(0)
            If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                ' MsgBox("اسم االتصنيفل او رقمه موجود مسبقا ", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "رسالة تنبيه")
                receiptCode.Text = Format(Val(GetLastRecord("ReceiptOfItems", "receiptcode")) + 1, "REC0000000")
            End If
            Dim dr = dt.NewRow
            dr!receiptCode = receiptCode.Text
            dr!receiptDate = Format(receiptDate.Value, "yyyy/MM/dd")
            ' dr!receiptDate = receiptDate.Text
            dr!supplierCode = GetsupplierCode(supplierName.Text)
            dr!SupplierInvoiceCode = SupplierInvoiceCode.Text
            dr!supplierInvoiceDate = Format(supplierInvoiceDate.Value, "yyyy/MM/dd")
            'dr!supplierInvoiceDate = supplierInvoiceDate.Text
            dr!TotalDiscount = Val(TotalDiscount.Text)
            dr!TotalReceipt = Val(TotalReceipt.Text)
            dr!TotalArabic = TotalArabic.Text
            dr!SupplierInvoiceType = SupplierInvoiceType.Text
            dr!salesTax = Val(salesTax.Text)
            dr!note = note.Text
            dr!status = True
            dt.Rows.Add(dr)
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommandBuilder(dta)
```

Comment: What did you try?  How did it fail?  All you have here is a single `SELECT` statement (with a glaring SQL injection vulnerability, by the way), so what operations are you even trying to contain within a transaction?

Comment: i have tried this in side this code    ' Dim transaction As SqlTransaction
                ' transaction = con.BeginTransaction()
                '  dta.UpdateCommand.Transaction = transaction
                ' transaction.Commit()

Comment: and i don't do that for business MR Steve i just do this in my freetime :) that is why it is normal sql without any parameters or other things

Comment: `"that is why it is normal sql without any parameters or other things"` - That statement makes no sense.  What SQL *wouldn't* be "normal SQL"?  And you should really look into using query parameters.  Executing any code that your users send you is a pretty dangerous practice.  As for the transaction, in what way does it fail?

Comment: i can't speak English well and i didn't study programming in English that is why i don't know how explain and  wrote normal SQL ,, thanks for ur time ^_^ and ur help of course

Comment: Well, regardless of language, you're still going to want to look into using query parameters instead of directly concatenating input like you're currently doing.  What you have there is called a SQL injection vulnerability, and it's a very common (and very easily solved) security problem.

Comment: @AbdulahBensasi have you tried the solution below?  Did it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
    con.Open()
    Dim trans As SqlTransaction = con.BeginTransaction()
    Try
        Dim insertStr As String = "insert into ReceiptOfItems (receiptCode, receiptDate, etc.) values(@receiptCode, @receiptDate, @etc)"
        Dim insertCmd As New SqlCommand(insertStr, con, trans)
        For Each dc As DataColumn In dt.Columns
            Dim param As New SqlParameter()
            param.ParameterName = dc.ColumnName
            param.SourceColumn = dc.ColumnName
            insertCmd.Parameters.Add(param)
        Next
        dta.InsertCommand = insertCmd

        dta.Update(ds)
        trans.Commit()
        con.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        trans.Rollback()
    End Try
```

The DataAdapter class has an UpdateCommand and a DeleteCommand property which must be built appropriately if you are doing something other than inserting new rows.